# How to solve this 'SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression' in pm2

Tags: node.js, pm2

I install node.js with pm2, all install fine but when i try to do `pm2 monit` give me this error.

```
$ pm2 monit
/home/node/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/fast-printf/dist/src/tokenize.js:4
const TokenRule = /(?:%(?<flag>([+0-]|-\+))?(?<width>\d+)?(?<position>\d+\$)?(?<precision>\.\d+)?(?<conversion>[%BCESb-iosux]))|(\\%)/g;
                  ^

SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?:%(?<flag>([+0-]|-\+))?(?<width>\d+)?(?<position>\d+\$)?(?<precision>\.\d+)?(?<conversion>[%BCESb-iosux]))|(\\%)/: Invalid group
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/node/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/fast-printf/dist/src/tokenize.js:4:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/node/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/fast-printf/dist/src/createPrintf.js:5:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
```

I tried servers nodejs version and always give me this error.

Comment: Your node version is really old. Have you tried installing a newer version?

Answer (score 0):

If you paste your regular expression into a regex sandbox, like this one:

https://regex101.com/r/GkwWH2/1

You'll see that it doesn't show any syntax errors.

That would make me suspect that you're running a back-level version of Node JS. And in fact, if you look at your stack trace, you see that you are running Node 8.11.3

> ```
> at Object.<anonymous> (/home/node/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/fas
> ```

That regular expression is using features (such as named capture groups) that did not come into Node.js until Node v10.*.

I suggest you update to the latest LTS version of Node, version 14.*: from your stack trace it would appear that you're using NVM, so it should be a simple matter of

```sh
sudo nvm install lts/fermium
```

should do it.

Comment: I'm using nodejs 8 because my app can't more early versions.

So i'm downgrade pm2 to version 4 and now its working.

I can inform pm2 5.0 version only work with nodejs >=10, if you want to run nodejs =<8 then you need to run pm2 version 4.